# CppUnit - how use unique_ptr in setUp()

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, cppunit

The code is taken from http://cppunit.sourceforge.net/doc/cvs/cppunit_cookbook.html
here they are creating pointers on the heap and deleted them in tearDown()

```
private:
  Complex *m_10_1, *m_1_1, *m_11_2;
public:
  void setUp()
  {
    m_10_1 = new Complex( 10, 1 );
    m_1_1 = new Complex( 1, 1 );
    m_11_2 = new Complex( 11, 2 );  
  }

  void tearDown() 
  {
    delete m_10_1;
    delete m_1_1;
    delete m_11_2;
  }

  void testEquality()
  {
    CPPUNIT_ASSERT( *m_10_1 == *m_10_1 );
    CPPUNIT_ASSERT( !(*m_10_1 == *m_11_2) );
  }

  void testAddition()
  {
    CPPUNIT_ASSERT( *m_10_1 + *m_1_1 == *m_11_2 );
  }
};
```

But If I would like to use unique_ptr instead. What is the lifetime of unique_ptr? Are they deleted at the end of SetUp()? And I should create an instance in every test? Is it possible to avoid code duplication with unique_ptr?

```
private:
  std::unique_ptr<Complex> m_10_1;
  std::unique_ptr<Complex> m_1_1;
  std::unique_ptr<Complex> m_11_2;
public:
  void setUp()
  {
    m_10_1.reset(new Complex(10, 1));
    m_1_1.reset(new Complex(1, 1)); 
    m_11_2.reset(new Complex(11, 2));  
  }

  void tearDown() 
  {

  }

  void test1()
  {
    // some tests with usage of ptr.
    m_10_1.reset(new Complex(10, 1)); // Should be here insted setUp() ??
  }

  void test2()
  {
     // some tests with usage of ptr.
    m_10_1.reset(new Complex(10, 1)); // Should be here insted setUP() ??
  }
};
```

Comment: Don't use `new`. The whole point of smart pointers is to let them handle memory allocation/deallocation. So, using C++14: `m_10_1 = std::make_unique<Complex>(10, 1);`

Answer (score 0):

Those will exist as long as the containing object exists. The unique_ptr's destructor is called implicitly when the containing object is destroyed. So whenever the `ComplexNumberTest` is destroyed, those heap allocated objects will as well.

If you have access to c++14 consider using std::make_unique.